# Limit of 1 category

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

The limit of **0** is the terminal object

The limit of discrete categories $\geq 2$ are products.

But what is the limit of the discrete category with one object, **1**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A functor $F:\mathbf{1}\to C$ is determined by just a choice of an object $X$ of $C$ to send the one object of $\mathbf{1}$ to.  The limit of $F$ is then just $X$ itself (with the identity map $X\to X$).  I will leave it as an exercise to prove this has the required universal property.